# is there an equivalent of Python self-documenting expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

in Python 3.8 it is possible to use self-documenting expressions in f-strings like this:

```
>>> variable=5
>>> print(f'{variable=}')
variable=5
```

is there an equivalent feature in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable way to do something like this would be for properties of objects:

```js
const logObj = (obj) => {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key, val);
  }
};
const obj = {
  foo: 'fooval',
  bar: 'barval',
};
logObj(obj);
```

There's no good way to do this for standalone variables. But the execution logic of a script should not (and, indeed, almost always does not) depend on the names of the variables used in the script - that would break [minification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/minification#:%7E:text=Minification%20is%20the%20process%20of,of%20variable%20and%20function%20names) and would be confusing to other readers of the script. Even if it might be theoretically possible to do something like

```
logVar(someVar)
```

and have the string `someVar` be logged (such as by throwing an error and examining the source text), that would be an extraordinary strange thing to do.

Comment: this feature is useful for debugging. and it helps to improve code readability by reducing the length of logging lines in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can self-assign a variable into an object and stringify it:

```js
let variable = 5;
console.log(JSON.stringify({variable}));
```